# ATL1E : Interrupt coalescing / ringbuffer / offloads settings

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, network-interface

According to `lshw`, I get a :

product: AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
driver=ATL1E driverversion=1.0.0.7-NAPI (from linux-5.4)

---

I would like to find a way to tune interrupt coalescing and; if possible size of ring buffer and misc. offloadings

But whatever I can try using `ethtool` returns that the feature is not supported, (most probably because of a very limited [atl1e_ethtool](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.195/source/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1e/atl1e_ethtool.c) (*1))

---

Parameters commanding to those settings appear hardcoded into [atl1e_param.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.195/source/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1e/atl1e_param.c), and scrolling down further, one can discover the atl1e_check_options routine which *"checks all command line parameters for valid user input."* and modifies default hardcoded parameters accordingly.

I deduce that the module would support boot command line parameters of the kind `atl1e.param_name=value` **BUT**…

BUT I just cannot find any clue about list of accepted param_names.

Could one help me finding them ?

---

1 : suboptimal ethtool suspected here since I know from the [ale freeBSD driver](https://nxmnpg.lemoda.net/4/if_ale) that "*All LOMs supported by the ale driver have TCP/UDP/IP checksum offload for both receive and transmit, TCP segmentation offload (TSO), hardware VLAN tag stripping/insertion features, Wake On Lan (WOL) and an interrupt coalescing/moderation mechanism as well as a 64-bit multicast hash filter.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I managed to find my way through atl1e source code and because of erroneous code comments I found there and, even more, because this facility is documented absolutely nowhere on earth, I post what follows as an answer & will accept it.

---

**WHAT :**

Linux ATL1E driver does accept a couple of parameters enabling miscellaneous tunings reported not supported by suboptimal ethtool :

- **tx_desc_cnt** : *Transmit Description Count* : 32 <= value <= 1020 : Default 128

for those who would have wished to use the unsupported `ethtool -G tx <value>` in order to change the number of tx ring entries.

< MyOpinion > Default is far too high for whatever home router / desktop lan. Keeping this setting insensibly wastes RAM, not to say the unreasonable increase of whatever kernel crashdump size. To be at least halved. < /MyOpinion >

- **rx_mem_size** : *Memory size of rx buffer(KB)* : 8 <= value <= 1024 : Default 256

for those who would have wished to use the unsupported `ethtool -G rx <value>` in order to change the size of the receive ring buffer.

< MyOpinion > I wanted to increase that from default in order to decrease the amount of rx overruns… Hmmm… it possibly does… but in… a somehow not significantly noticeable amount. However… increasing it does significantly increases network latency. < /MyOpinion >

- **media_type** : *MediaType Select* : 0 <= value <= 4 : Default 0

0 - auto-negotiate at all supported speeds
1 - only link at 100Mbps Full Duplex
2 - only link at 100Mbps Half Duplex
3 - only link at 10Mbps Full Duplex
4 - only link at 10Mbps Half Duplex

for those who would have wished to use the unsupported `ethtool -s advertise <value>` in order to force the speed and duplex advertised.

< MyOpinion > Only those experiencing problems with default autonegociation will want that parameter's value to differ from null < /MyOpinion >

- **int_mod_timer**, *Interrupt Moderate Timer in units of 2 µs* : 50 <= value <= 65000 : default 100

for those who would have wished to use the unsupported `ethtool -C [rx/tx]-usecs <value>` in order to change the coalescing settings.

< MyOpinion > **THE** setting that gets the greatest impact on the system. Benchmark and benchmark and benchmark again running your typical workload (network traffic)… since… there is no free lunch… higher the value, the lesser the NET_RX/TX software interrupts, the lesser the time spent servicing IRQs… BUT… the higher network latency. < /MyOpinion >

And… ? And that's all folks, you just cannot expect more from this driver as-is. Checksum offloading ? TSO ? Oh well… never mind !

---

**HOW TO :**

Simply append some string to your boot command line, that will work whether you built your driver in-kernel or as a module :

```
atl1e.<any_one of above parameter_name>=<value>
```

OK, you get several NICs ? No problem this is just an array :

```
atl1e.<any_one of above parameter_name>=<value_for_NIC0>,<value_for_NIC1>,…
```

OK you just hate the kernel command line, built this driver as module and  want to use modprobe ? Then simply :

```
modprobe atl1e <any_one of above parameter_name>=<value_for_NIC0>,<value_for_NIC1>,…
```

---

**ON A SIDE NOTE :** MSI capabilities

Corresponding hardware should be MSI capable, however
Because some sombre hot shot, sometime, on its hardware encountered some sombre trouble with it, some patch was applied in order to disable this capability, falling back to some IRQ.

Because of my hardware, my NIC would have shared the IRQ with one of my sound cards ! Horresco referens !!

I simply reverted the patch, tested and tested again… well… everything has been working trouble-free with MSI enabled for the last 10 years. I will provide more info about this on demand.

---

**CONCLUSION :**

I do realize that corresponding hardware has, at the time of writing, done more than just bordering on obsolescence… (so has the author of these lines…) and that therefore… this Tl;Dr answer won't help many here around.
I'd be happy to help whoever having had the courage to read that far :

- Never blindly trust kernel quirks ! Benchmark and benchmark and benchmark again your own system. You'll know more about it than whatever kernel dev can.
- Never trust ethtool when getting this stupid *Operation not supported* verdict. Many companies editing drivers don't care much about providing ethtool helpers and care even less about documentation… therefore… dig into the code : **When there is a will, there is a way!**