# ksoftirqd taking a lot of cpu since moving to debian 12

Tags: debian, iptables, drivers, nftables, proprietary-drivers

I have a small pc linux box like intel nuc dual atom where I run some firewall settings.

Previously this machine runned debian 9 and everything worked fine.

I could have used the machine in middle of 2 others to send data at very high speed around 50-70MB/s transfer rate (gigabit ethernet).

Now since I moved the setup to debian 12 my rate dropped to 9-10MB/s, by looking for an answer I found that ksoftirqd was taking a lot of cpu.

I tried raising the MTU from 1500 to 3000 but I achieved only a small improvement like 16 MB/s (while still maxing out the cpu) and some adapters I'm using doesn't support MTU over 4000. My opinion is that there's something else that is not working correctly...

2 main things have changed from debian 9:

- iptables is now nftables
- the driver on that machine if I remember correctly was installed from manifacturer, now is provided directly in debian 12 via the non-free-firmware package

what settings or log can I inspect to solve the problem?
can be some settings be changed to allow more resources being used (like ram) in order to allow longer irq queque and improve the throughput or tell nftables to treat all subsequent packages of the same type in the same way speeding up everything up?

Comment: Please, watch the output of grep softirq /proc/stat at different times and try to isolate and identify which number(s) is(are) increasing rapidly and to which softirqs they precisely relate.

Comment: @MC68020 ok I tried but it seems almost all counters increase rapidly, also how can I understand to wich softirqs do they relate?

Comment: *"it seems almost all counters increase rapidly"* you wrote ? OK… I can tell you one good news : *"ksoftirqd taking a lot of cpu"* is indeed, in such circumstances, nothing but… normal. OK then… now… bad news… such circumstances are not standard. It smells something like some sort of race condition somewhere. The kind of things I feel just incapable to trace remotely. I wish you good luck with this one and at least hope you'll find someone more capable than I can be. And BTW, please, tell us regarding any progress achieved.

Comment: @MC68020 ok, I have checked the /proc/softirqs and between the various interrupts I say one of them that has a very big amount is NET_RX, considering also that NET_TX has none.

Comment: OK then please what does *ethtool -c the_network_device_name* report ?

Comment: @MC68020 Ok the fun part is that if I do that for the wan interface it works, but if I do that for the interfaces I'm interested into it fails saying that the interface doesn't accept the command. I'm using for the data transfer 2 usb3 gigabit lan adapters, could be this be related to usb interrupts or something?

Comment: *fun* ? Hmmm… not sure. I would like to see the impact of increasing interrupt coalescing. This mustApparently… they did not. However… dedicated driver's parameters should be available for tuning at modprobe time. =>…

Comment: …Con't… 1/ Can you find somewhere any sort of documentation relating to the patented official driver. 2/ If not, is the driver closed-source or can source code be available so that we can expect finding what the parameters are from reading the code. (I've done that successfully in the past (   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713859/426539 )

Comment: @MC68020 How can I determine the model name in order to investigate further?

Comment: errr ? I see you mentioned *"usb3 gigabit lan adapters"* There must be something engraved on this piece of hardware. If not then you could fire *lsusb -v* and it cannot tell anything of interest then… you are screwed.

Comment: @MC68020 I just tried moving 150 GB worth of data between 2 machines using this interfaces and by reading "cat /proc/softirqs" the NET_RX on CPU0 is 2.550.000 while on CPU1 is 25.000 only, so I was thinking of installing the irqbalance package to better divide the interrupts among the 2 CPUs. I know that this would not explain why all these interrupts are fired but could improve the performances along with shifting the MTU to 3000. Probably is something engraved in this hardware but in debian9 this would not happen so there should be a mix of things.

Comment: The devices in question are 2 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet, if there's anything else that I can fetch from the data let me know :)